# How to change text of Text View outside of onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to change the text of a `TextView` on my Activity. It happens in a method in the same class as the `onCreate` method. However, it does not work. I've googled it but found nothing.

**This is the error I got:**

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference.

**This is the Main Activity, where my `TextView` is located:**

```
    private static TextView welcome;
    private static TextView counter;
    private static int number;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Shared Preferences getting called to see if the user has set his name
        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Getting number
        this.number = sharedpreferences.getInt("number", 0);
        this.sharedPreferences = sharedpreferences;

        Boolean continueName = false;
        //Checking if name is set
        if (!sharedpreferences.getBoolean("nameSet", false)) {
            //If name is not set
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Name.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            //if name was already set, default activity pops Up
            continueName = true;
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getting counter and setting it
        TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
        this.counter = count;

        //Actionlistener to +1 Button
        ActionListeners al = new ActionListeners();
        Button plusOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddOne);
        plusOne.setOnClickListener(al.getPlusOneListener());

        //Setting Text View Object
        this.welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeUser);

        //If the name is set
        if (continueName) {
            this.welcome.setText(getString(R.string.welcome) + " " + sharedpreferences.getString("usersName", ""));
        }
    }

    public void setNameNew() throws InterruptedException {
        TextView welcomeThis = this.welcome;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Setting welcome text
                SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                welcomeThis.setText(getString(R.string.welcome) + " " + sp.getString("usersName", ""));
            }
        });
        Thread.sleep(500);
        this.welcome.setText(welcomeThis.getText());
    }

        public void changeViewNumber(int number) {
        //Setting new number
        this.counter.setText(number);
    }
}
```

Weird is, that the `setNameNew` method is working and can change the text of the `TextField`. But the `changeViewNumber` method is not working.

Im on the activity where the `TextView` is located. I can't figure it out. May you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I tried to set the text of a `TextView` with an `Integer`
The fix was:

```
String numberString = Integer.toString(number);
counter.setText(numberString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call setText for a TextView anywhere in the class as long as the TextView is referenced. When you say one function is working and the other isn't, it's because the reference for the counter is incorrect.

Your `counter` reference

```
TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
this.counter = count;
```

Your `welcome` reference

```
 this.welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeUser);
```

You should be referencing the view the way you referenced `welcome`. You'll want to change the counter reference to the following.

```
this.counter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNumber)
```

Your count variable does nothing and should be removed.

I would also like to make additional notes for your code. You are using the keyword `this`, it isn't necessary for your code.

The `this` keyword refers to the current object in a method or constructor.

The most common use of the `this` keyword is to eliminate the confusion between class attributes and parameters with the same name (because a class attribute is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

I would also strongly recommend not putting the main thread to sleep, if the thread is sleeping and action is required it will cause your app to crash.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. I now removed all of the ```this``` keywords and changed the ```counter``` reference. It still crashes. 

I also removed the ```Thread.sleep()``` but now, if the user saves the name, and it goes back to the activity, it does not change the welcome ```TextView``` how can I make it wait, until the new Activity is loaded, so it can then set the welcome ```TextView```

Comment: It seems like you have multiple issues going on here, and I'm not entirely sure what you are asking now. Do you have your project posted to Github, I would be happy to review it.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. Here is my repository: https://github.com/gi-oel/Counter

Answer (score 0):

This is useless

```
TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
this.counter = count;
```

Just do

```
counter = findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
```

Comment: Oh nice, thank you. I guess I was stupid xD

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've declared **welcome** variable globally in class and initialized in onCreate but you forget to initialize **counter** on the OnCreate method which is why it is throwing a null pointer exception.

```
this.counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
```

just initialize your counter variable just like you did on your welcome variable.

Comment: I did declared counter here in onCreate()
```//getting counter and setting it
        TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
        this.counter = count;```